# validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

If an address polo Rd is given, it identifies "po" in  polo and alerts error message.

So, we should frame a new validation which should not accept address lines 1 and 2 with the values:

- "PO BOX",  "PO BIN",  "BIN", "P.O BOX", "P.O BIN", "P.O", "PO"
- the above values can be in any case
- spaces before, in between  and after the above words should also be found and validated. For example:  "    P  O    1234    "  should be validated and alert error message.
- But "Polo Rd", "Robin Rd", "testbintest" should be accepted as valid address in both the address lines

the code which is writen for this is

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nopobox", function(value, element) {
     return this.optional(element) || ! /(P(OST)?\.?\s*O(FF(ICE)?)?\.?\s*((BOX)|(BIN)))|(^[^0-9]*((P(OST)?\.?\s*O(FF(ICE)?)?\.?)|((BOX)|(BIN))))/i.test(value);
}, "");
```

Please let me know how I can change it

Comment: I think some of your coditions exclude other conditions, for example you want `BIN` to fail validation but `testbintest` to pass it, however you say that `BIN` can be in any case and any position in a input string.

Comment: yes P.O.BIN should fail but normal address lines line robin street or hobin road should pass the validation

Answer (score 2):

**edit**

I played around with this a bit... don't know if this will match 100% of your cases but try this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>testing...</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nopobox", function(value, element) {
     return ! /(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s?[o|0](?:\.|ffice)?)\b|(?:b(?:[o|0]x)|(?:in))\b/i.test(value);
}, "PO Boxes are not allowed.");

$(document).ready(function() {$('#test').validate({rules: {address: {nopobox: false, required: true}}})}); 
      </script>
   </head>
   </body>
      <form id="test" action="#">
         <input type="textbox" id="address" class="required nopobox" />
         <input type="submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I run this I get the "PO Boxes are not allowed" error on: PO, po, p.o, p.o., po box, box, bin, etc, etc.  But polo road, testboxtest, etc: no warning.  One bug: po road throws and error... I'm not sure you can test 100% of the cases in a single Regex.

**end edit**

Ok... the Regex master don't seem to be online... I'll give it a shot:

Try this regex `(?:(?:p(?:[o|0]st)?\.?(?:[o|0](?:ffice)?\.?))|(?:b[o|0]x|bin))(?=\s\d)`

It give me the following in the [powertoy](http://regex.powertoy.org/): (entered as: `s/(?:(?:p(?:[o|0]st)?\.?(?:[o|0](?:ffice)?\.?))|(?:b[o|0]x|bin))(?=\s\d)/**NO PO BOXES**/i` for testing.

Matches:

- PO BOX 123
- PO BIN 1
- BIN 1
- P.O BOX 134
- P.O BIN 12
- P.O 12
- P.o. 12
- PO 123

Does not match:

- 123 boxing road
- 123 box road
- 123 polo road

Comment: Its not working and the basic requirement is  polo road should be positive but PO box should throw an error Please respond me soon thanks the code when I am replacng it its trowing syntax error
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nopobox", function(value, element) {
     return this.optional(element) || ! s/(?:(?:p(?:[o|0]st)?\.?(?:[o|0](?:ffice)?\.?))|(?:b[o|0]x|bin))(?=\s\d)/**NO PO BOXES**/i for testing.;
}, "");

Comment: I want poland road , robin road to be working but po box or po bin should throw an error can you please help me out with this logic to write the regex please

Comment: I've done my best (see edit above) and it seems to work in most cases, someone better as regex/jquery will have to help now.

Comment: HI beggs it looks kool but the robin road is also throwing an error do you have any clue what makes this robin or robox road work in your code?

Comment: Sorry it gives a false positive on anything that ends with 'in' because the 'b' is only grouped with the '[o|0]x, `(?:p(?:ost)?\.?\s?[o|0](?:\.|ffice)?\b)|(?:\bb(?:(?:[o|0]x)|(?:in)))\s[\d]+` fixes that. However I an not sure that this will solve all your issues.  You need to exhaustively test it.  I did a bit of testing, polo road = valid, po = invalid, post office = invalid, box = valid, bin = valid, box 123 = invalid, bin 123 = invalid, robin road = valid, etc...